# How to take thread dump in Linux environment using jboss-eap-5.1 server

Tags: jboss

How to take thread dump in Linux environment using jboss-eap-5.1 server And how to save that thread dump file in specific file. can any one please share the commands to generate thread dump when the server is start.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to get the PID of the JBoss server and [jstack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstack.html), which is part of the HotSpot JDK (and OpenJDK, I believe), then write the output to a new file. If the PID of JBoss is 1234:

```
jstack -l 1234 >> myThread.dmp
```

The double arrow bracket will create the file if it does not exist, or append to it if it does exist, so you can take multiple thread dumps and save to the same file (useful for seeing changes over time).

You can find the PID of JBoss either using the linux ps command and grepping for Java:

```
ps aux | grep java
```

Or simply with JPS (another tool which comes with the JDK) and the "-v" verbose option:

```
jps -v
```

This answer is applicable to any Java application.

***Note:*** To do this on JRockit JVM, use `jrcmd <pid> print_threads` instead of jstack